# How to copy all the nodes except one when a condition is true

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have got the following XML.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <Students>
      <Student>
       <StdId value="1"/>
       <Name>a</Name>
       <Courses>
         <Course Id="2" value="c1"/>
        <Course Id="3" value="c2"/>
        <Course Id="4" value="c3"/>
       </Courses>
       <Addresses>
         <Address Id="2" type="permanent">
            <address1>my address</address1>
        </Address>
        <Address Id="4" type="Temporary">
            <address1>my address temp address</address1>
        </Address>
       </Addresses>
      </Student>
      <Student>
       <StdId value="2" InActive="True"/>
       <Name>b</Name>
       <Courses>
         <Course Id="2" value="c1"/>
        <Course Id="3" value="c4"/>
        <Course Id="5" value="c6"/>
       </Courses>
       <Addresses>
        <Address Id="2" type="permanent">
            <address1>my address</address1>
        </Address>
       </Addresses>
      </Student>
     </Students>
```

And my xslt is

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
     <xsl:variable name="list" >1 4 6 15</xsl:variable> 
     <xsl:template match="/">       
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file:///C:/Student_details.xml">
        <xsl:for-each select="Students/Student">                
            <xsl:variable name="vv1" select="Addresses/Address/@id" /> 
            <xsl:variable name="vv2" select="Courses/Course/@id" /> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($list, $vv1)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select=". except(Addresses)" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($list, $vv2)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select=". except(Courses)" /> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to filter some nodes based on the condition. When the address @id value is in the list then copy every thing except the addresses and its child. When the Course @id value is in the list then copy every thing except courses and its child node. when none of the above conditions are true then copy every thing. My XSLT code copy every thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your input sample has `Id` attributes, not `id` attributes, so in the XPath to select the input you need `@Id`. I am not sure I understand your requirement, assuming you really want to remove any `Courses` if one is found in the list respectively any `Addresses`, you can simply use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="list" >1 4 6 15</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ids" select="tokenize($list, '\s+')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Student/Courses[Course/@Id = $ids] | Student/Addresses[Address/@Id = $ids]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

For the input sample you have given that creates the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Students>
   <Student>
      <StdId value="1"/>
      <Name>a</Name>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <StdId value="2" InActive="True"/>
      <Name>b</Name>
      <Courses>
         <Course Id="2" value="c1"/>
         <Course Id="3" value="c4"/>
         <Course Id="5" value="c6"/>
      </Courses>
      <Addresses>
         <Address Id="2" type="permanent">
            <address1>my address</address1>
         </Address>
      </Addresses>
   </Student>
</Students>
```

If you want to explicitly create a result document use e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="list" >1 4 6 15</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ids" select="tokenize($list, '\s+')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Student/Courses[Course/@Id = $ids] | Student/Addresses[Address/@Id = $ids]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that you had `<xsl:variable name="list" >1 4 6 15</xsl:variable>` in your original code which is not really a list respectively a sequence of values, therefore I used `<xsl:variable name="ids" select="tokenize($list, '\s+')"/>` to create a sequence programmatically. It is however also possible to simply define the variable value as a sequence of integers doing `<xsl:variable name="ids" select="1, 4, 6, 15"/>`, that way you don't need the tokenize call.

Comment: @Mertin Honnen Thanks for your answer. how do i write this out put to the file  <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file:///C:/Student_details.xml">.

Comment: Add a template `<xsl:template match="/">       
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file:///C:/Student_details.xml"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:result-document></xsl:template>`

Comment: I have tried your code. it work's but it only ignore that particular node. I want to exclude the whole Courses and it's sub nodes and in the case of  Address condition true, exclude the Addresses element and it's sub nodes.

Comment: Well I posted the result I get, as you can see the first `Student` element has neither a `Courses` nor an `Addresses` child element. You will need to edit your question and show us the exact result you want for the input sample you posted.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i have placed the "[" in the wrong location. Thanks again that solved my issue.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Why not simply: `<xsl:variable name="vIds" select="1, 4, 6, 15"/>` ?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, mainly because the original code has `<xsl:variable name="list" >1 4 6 15</xsl:variable>` and I tried to process that input data. But I agree, I should have mentioned that it is as well possible and more straight-forward in XSLT 2.0 to directly define a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Good, then it would be best for the readers if you edit the answer and make that point.